# How to programmatically set Font DPI?

Tags: kde, plasma

In the kde plasma settings page there's the Font DPI settings (Appearance > Global Theme >Fonts > Force Font DPI).

Occasionally this is reset, and I must open the GUI to reset it to the appropriate value. How can I set this value from command line and apply the changes?

Comment: Could have helped if I'd had KDE installed but I don't. Please check this: https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/02/26/how-to-automate-kde-using-d-bus/